# Stuck messages in ZeroMQ

Tags: network-programming, message-queue, zeromq

I'm having a strange problem with ZeroMQ, in which some messages get stuck, and just get unstuck when new messages arrive. It's like the new messages push the stuck messages on the door (terrible comparison, i know).

My code is quite simple:

rep.php

```
$context = new ZMQContext;
$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->connect("tcp://localhost:8022");
$receiver2 = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver2->connect("tcp://localhost:8024");

for (;;) {
    echo $receiver->recv() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $receiver2->recv() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

cnt.php and cnt2.php (same code, different ports)

```
$context = new ZMQContext;
$work = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$work->bind('tcp://*:8022');
$work->send('Hello World');
```

cnt.php sends to 8022 and cnt2.php to 8024. They get executed from time to time and send messages to rep.php. However, some messages get stuck. If i sent 4 messages from cnt.php, nothing is received, but when i send 1 from cnt2.php, i get 5 messages at once. Any ideas?

Comment: Choice of variable name is suggestive and you could really do without it

Comment: That really doesn't matter. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no PHP expert here but guessing the syntax and functionality. Please correct me if I am wrong

```
echo $receiver->recv() . ' - ' . $receiver2->recv();
```

recv() should be a blocking call.

1. `$receiver->recv()` blocks until some message is received.
2. But `echo` does not echo the message immediately
3. You are again blocked on `$receiver2->recv()`
4. Only when you send message from the other file does echo work because it is waiting on `$receiver2->recv()`

Since you want to process the socket recv() independently, you should use polling or event based asynchronous I/O.

[**Attempted solution**]

```
$poll = new ZMQPoll();
$poll->add($receiver, ZMQ::POLL_IN);
$poll->add($receiver2, ZMQ::POLL_IN);
$readable = $writeable = array();
while(true) {
     $events = $poll->poll($readable, $writeable);
     foreach($readable as $socket) {
               $message = $socket->recv();
               echo $message, PHP_EOL;
     }
}
```

Adapted from : http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:rrbroker

Comment: What if i echo $receiver->recv() and then echo $receiver2->recv()?

Comment: rep.php is not a script, it's running all the time, waiting to receive messages.

Comment: I have changed the behavior, messages are still getting stuck. Check my edit.

Comment: @vinnylinux: I have added notes on how you can change red.php. See it might have PHP errors as I don't know PHP. I have also added the pointer that should be useful